# Sign in user on signup with Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I have authentication working with Sorcery. When users sign up, I want to automatically sign them in.

User_controller

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

if @user.save
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to Christian"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render :new
end
```

end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auto_login(user)` should do the trick:

```
...

if @user.save
  auto_login(@user)
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to Christian"
  redirect_to root_url

...
```